# C# SelectVoice not changing in windows application but does in console

Tags: c#, system, selector, voice, speech

So I am trying to change a voice in C# for the System.Speech.Synthesis library. It will work for me when I attempt the code in console mode. However when I am working on a windows application it does not change the voice while giving no errors. Here is the code of the windows application that works asside from the voice change.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace JarvisRev1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
            this.button2.Click += new EventHandler(button2_Click);
            this.button3.Click += new EventHandler(button3_Click);

            foreach (InstalledVoice voice in sSynth.GetInstalledVoices())
            {
                cbVoice.Items.Add(voice.VoiceInfo.Name);
            }
        }

        SpeechSynthesizer sSynth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        PromptBuilder pBuilder = new PromptBuilder();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sRecognize = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pBuilder.ClearContent();
            pBuilder.AppendText(textBox1.Text);
            sSynth.SelectVoice("IVONA 2 Brian");
            sSynth.SpeakAsync(pBuilder);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;
            Choices sList = new Choices();
            sList.Add(new string[] { "hello", "test", "it works", "how", "are", "you", "today", "i", "am", "fine", "exit", "close", "quit", "so", "hello how are you" });
            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));
            try
            {
                sRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                sRecognize.LoadGrammar(gr);
                sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
                sRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                sRecognize.Recognize();
            }

            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sRecognize.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            button2.Enabled = true;
            button3.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.Result.Text == "exit")
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

This is the code in console mode that is working for me.

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;  // Add reference to System.Speech

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        synth.SelectVoice("IVONA 2 Brian");
        synth.SpeakAsync("For you Sir, Always.");
        foreach (var voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(voice.VoiceInfo.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this code cbVoice is not working
foreach (InstalledVoice voice in sSynth.GetInstalledVoices())
            {
                `cbVoice`.Items.Add(voice.VoiceInfo.Name);
            }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have same issue when Microsoft Irina Desktop voice is available in system. Workaround to set voice explicitly in prompt, e.g.:

```
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

var synth=new SpeechSynthesizer();
var builder=new PromptBuilder();
builder.StartVoice("Microsoft David Desktop");
builder.AppendText("Hello, World!");
builder.EndVoice();
synth.SpeakAsync(new Prompt(builder));
```

As you already utilize PromptBuilder, try to add **StartVoice** and **EndVoice** calls around text.

Comment: No idea where the problem is?